# How to change rotate background-image, if block is styled by "skew"

Tags: css, background-image, css-transforms, skew

I have some problem and, I think this problem will not have solved. [Style and code bottom]
[image]

```
.box-blog {
  background: url(../img/image.png) center no-repeat;
  background-size: cver;
  width: 80%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 71px;
  height: 192px;
  border-radius: 0 40px;
  -webkit-transform: skew(20deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(20deg);
  -o-transform: skew(20deg);
  background-color: #333;
  box-shadow: 15px 0 0 rgba(248,48,46,.3);
}`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common solution is to use **pseudo-element** for the background image and create the inverse **skew** on it :

```css
.box-blog {
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 71px;
  height: 192px;
  border-radius: 0 40px;
  transform: skew(20deg);
  background-color: #333;
  box-shadow: 15px 0 0 rgba(248, 48, 46, .3);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box-blog:before {
  content: " ";
  background: url(https://lorempixel.com/400/400/) center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -40px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: -40px;
  transform: skew(-20deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="box-blog">

</div>
```

This can be a generic solution for any kind of tranformation and you have two situations :

- Transform the element without transforming the background : you transform the element and you create the inverse tranformation on the pseudo-element like we did
- Transform the background without transforming the element : you simply add the transformation to the pseudo-element.

You need also to becarefull about any overflow issue.